# Optimize SQL query with three SELECT

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
news
idNews | title
1      | Title 1
2      | Title 2
3      | Title 3
4      | Title 4

tags
idTag | name
1     | Name_tag1
2     | Name_tag2
3     | Name_tag3
4     | Name_tag4
```

The MappingTable:

```
tag_news
idTag | idNews
1     | 1
2     | 1
1     | 2
2     | 2
2     | 3
3     | 3
4     | 3
4     | 4
```

I want to fetch the title of the related news that have almost one tag in common by giving one idNews. I am be able to do this with three SELECT:

```
SELECT title FROM news WHERE idNews IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT idNews FROM tag_news 
  WHERE idTag IN 
  (SELECT idTag FROM tag_news WHERE idNews='$idNews'))
```

Where $idNews id the ID that I give by parameter.

This works well, but I thought if there is another way to improve the query.

Thanks in advance,
Iker

Comment: What SQL database are you using? Could you not run a join query on the tables?

Comment: Please learn about using parametrized queries as well, so you are not passing untrusted data into your SQL code.  http://bobby-tables.com gives examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you program in SQL, you really need to understand joins.  Joins are fundamental to SQL just as a while loop is fundamental to most other programming languages.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.title FROM news n
INNER JOIN tag_news t1 ON t1.idNews = n.idNews
INNER JOIN tag_news t2 ON t1.idTag = t2.idTag
WHERE t2.idNews = $idNews;
```

Start with [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

Re comments from @Beth:

I don't mean to contradict you, but I'm pretty sure my query is correct, and it doesn't need three joins.  Here's how it works:

- `t2` is the set of rows in `tag_news` where `t2.idNews=$idNews`.  For example, if $idNews=1 then this produces the following rows:

  ```
  idTag | idNews
  1     | 1
  2     | 1
  ```
- From there, we want all other rows in tag_news that match any of the same tags.  So `t1.idTag=t2.idTag`.  This produces gives us rows where `t1.idTag IN (1,2)`:

  ```
  idTag | idNews
  1     | 1
  2     | 1
  1     | 2
  2     | 2
  2     | 3
  ```
- From there, return all the rows in `news` that match any value of `t1.idNews`.  In other words, where `news.idNews IN (1,2,3)`.

  ```
  idNews | title
  1      | Title 1
  2      | Title 2
  3      | Title 3
  ```

Comment: Bill, you need to join t1 and t2 on idnews and idtag: t1.idnews = t2.idtag

Comment: @Beth, no, I got it right.  You reversed the columns of the OP's sample data.

Comment: it's this part of his post:SELECT
idTag FROM tag_news WHERE 
idNews=.  you can't get there from idnews = idnews and idtag = idtag

Comment: actually, I think we both got it wrong.  I needed to add another instance of the table.  yes, the joins are on the same field names, like you have, but he needs another level of indirection before determining the title.

Comment: @Beth, no, see explanation above.

Comment: I see yours is better from the execution plans.  I didn't want to add a third instance of the table, I see my head's screwed up today.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT distinct title 
FROM  
tag_news t1  inner join 
tag_news t2 on
t1.idnews = t2.idnews inner join
tag_news t3 on
t2.idtag = t3.idtag inner join
news n on
n.idnews = t3.idnews
WHERE t1.idNews='$idNews'
```

sorry, missed it the first and second times:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].news(
    idnews [int] NOT NULL,
    title [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into news(idnews, title) values(1,'title 1')
insert into news(idnews, title) values(2,'title 2')
insert into news(idnews, title) values(3,'title 3')
insert into news(idnews, title) values(4,'title 4')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].tag_news(
    idtag [int] NOT NULL,
    idnews [int] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(1,1)
insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(2,1)
insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(1,2)
insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(2,2)
insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(2,3)
insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(3,3)
insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(4,3)
insert into tag_news(idtag, idnews) values(4,4)

select * from news; 
select * from tag_news;

SELECT title FROM news WHERE idNews IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT idNews FROM tag_news 
  WHERE idTag IN 
  (SELECT idTag FROM tag_news WHERE idNews=1));

SELECT distinct title 
FROM  
tag_news t1  inner join 
tag_news t2 on
t1.idnews = t2.idnews inner join
tag_news t3 on
t2.idtag = t3.idtag inner join
news n on
n.idnews = t3.idnews
WHERE t1.idNews=1;
```

Comment: your sql simplified select title from news where idNews  = '$idNews'. All steps are needed there.

Comment: You reversed the columns of the OP's sample data for `tag_news`.